# displaying html from php

Tags: php, wordpress

this has to do with wordpress and php. i have a function that takes an array of names from json. for each name i loop through, it creates a div with the name and an image inside. this div is then attached to a post and displayed on the front end. the problem is the image doesn't display correctly due to a 404 error. when i looked at the image source, the path to the image looked like this:

`<img src="\"http://localhost/card-store/wp-content/themes/card-store-theme/images/baseball/team2.jpg\"">`

clearly the path is broken so the 404 makes sense. seems like php is trying to escape some quotes, so i tried removing this with the str_replace, and as a shot in the dark i also tried html_entity_decode. also tried an absolute path to my images but that did not work either. when i refresh the page, the images appear fine, so i think its something to do with it not compiling right away? if that is true, how can i get it to display correctly without refreshing the page?

```
function test_function() {
  if ( isset($_POST) ) {

        $nameData = $_POST['nameData'];

        //Strip any double escapes then use json_decode to create an array.
        $nameDecode =  json_decode(str_replace('\\', '', $_POST['nameData']));


        //loop through names array and create a container for each
        $html_string = "";

       foreach ($nameDecode as $keyIndex => $name) {
            $html_string .= '<div class="team-container team-container--inline col col--md-2 col--lg-2 col--xl-2"><img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/baseball/team' . $keyIndex . '.jpg"> <p>'.$name.' <p /></div>';

       }

        echo ( $html_string);

        //$html_final = str_replace('\\', '', $html_string);
        $html_final = html_entity_decode($html_string);

        // update teams post
        if($html_string != "") {
          $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => 9,
            'post_content' => $html_final,
        );

        // Update the post into the database
          wp_update_post( $my_post );
        } else {
          echo 'html string is empty!';
        }


    }
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the slashes try this.

```
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);


 $nameData = $_POST['nameData'];
$stringObject = json_decode(stripslashes($nameData));
```

For json encode

```
json_encode($html_string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i'm concerned with $html_final being posted. however i didn't know about stripslashes and i toyed with it a bit. the file path still displays the same. but i did notice it displayed the string i want when i used `json_encode` on the data first, and then `stripslashes`. so if `$html_final = stripslashes(json_encode($html_string))`, how do i properly add this to `post_content`? either that, or i have to remove the escaped double quotes within $html_string somehow.

Comment: Try  json_encode($html_string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);